# dont want few activities to be available in history

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a **Dashboard/Home** `Activity` where I show multiple icons to different `Activity`s.
My requirement is that, whenever I minimize my app I want to resume to **Home** `Activity` and not to any of the child activities.

I tried

```
noHistory="true"
```

in manifest for those child activities.

But one `Activity` e.g. A has its own child activities.so when I go to A and then its child `Activity` A_1 and press back I come to `Home` screen.

I have tried adding flag in intent

```
 FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting intent flag on minimize event.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(A_1.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

A-1, is the activity from where this event has been fired, and HomeActivity is the name of home/dashboard activity class.

Comment: you won while I was formatting the partial answer you pasted the complete one... +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use  [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) when you minimize the App.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I guess a less elegant approach would be to call finish() in the onPause() or onStop() methods of those child activities. This will make sure they are destroyed and will not be able to be returned to.